# helm parse error and fails with "function "X" not defined"

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to migrate a kustomize yaml file into helm, and seems like the origional yaml file is running a function inside:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |-
    # defaultTemplates defines the default template to use for pods that do not explicitly specify a template
    defaultTemplates: [sidecar]
    policy: enabled
    alwaysInjectSelector:
      []
    neverInjectSelector:
      []
    injectedAnnotations:
    template: "{{ Template_Version_And_Istio_Version_Mismatched_Check_Installation }}"
    templates:
      sidecar: |
        {{- $containers := list }}
        {{- range $index, $container := .Spec.Containers }}{{ if not (eq $container.Name "istio-proxy") }}{{ $containers = append $containers $container.Name }}{{end}}{{- end}}
        metadata:
          labels:
            security.istio.io/tlsMode: {{ index .ObjectMeta.Labels `security.istio.io/tlsMode` | default "istio"  | quote }}
            service.istio.io/canonical-name: {{ index .ObjectMeta.Labels `service.istio.io/canonical-name` | default (index .ObjectMeta.Labels `app.kubernetes.io/name`) | default (index .ObjectMeta.Labels `app`) | default .DeploymentMeta.Name  | quote }}
            service.istio.io/canonical-revision: {{ index .ObjectMeta.Labels `service.istio.io/canonical-revision` | default (index .ObjectMeta.Labels `app.kubernetes.io/version`) | default (index .ObjectMeta.Labels `version`) | default "latest"  | quote }}
          annotations: {
            {{- if eq (len $containers) 1 }}
            kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-logs-container: "{{ index $containers 0 }}",
            kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container: "{{ index $containers 0 }}",
            {{ end }}
        {{- if .Values.istio_cni.enabled }}
            {{- if not .Values.istio_cni.chained }}
            k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '{{ appendMultusNetwork (index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks`) `istio-cni` }}',
            {{- end }}
            sidecar.istio.io/interceptionMode: "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/interceptionMode` .ProxyConfig.InterceptionMode }}",
            {{ with annotation .ObjectMeta `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundIPRanges` .Values.global.proxy.includeIPRanges }}traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundIPRanges: "{{.}}",{{ end }}
            {{ with annotation .ObjectMeta `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges` .Values.global.proxy.excludeIPRanges }}traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundIPRanges: "{{.}}",{{ end }}
            traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts` `*` }}",
            traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: "{{ excludeInboundPort (annotation .ObjectMeta `status.sidecar.istio.io/port` .Values.global.proxy.statusPort) (annotation .ObjectMeta `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts` .Values.global.proxy.excludeInboundPorts) }}",
            {{ if or (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundPorts`) (ne (valueOrDefault .Values.global.proxy.includeOutboundPorts "") "") }}
            traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundPorts: "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundPorts` .Values.global.proxy.includeOutboundPorts }}",
            {{- end }}
            {{ if or (isset .ObjectMeta.Annotations `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts`) (ne .Values.global.proxy.excludeOutboundPorts "") }}
            traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts: "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts` .Values.global.proxy.excludeOutboundPorts }}",
            {{- end }}
            {{ with index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/kubevirtInterfaces` }}traffic.sidecar.istio.io/kubevirtInterfaces: "{{.}}",{{ end }}
        {{- end }}
          }
```

When I tried to migrate it into a helm chart template I get some syntax error:

```
Error: parse error at (istio-install/templates/install.yaml:1857): function "annotation" not defined
helm.go:84: [debug] parse error at (istio-install/templates/install.yaml:1857): function "annotation" not defined
```

What is a better way to define function within?

Comment: any luck resolving this issue?  I'm facing something similar while trying to inject a gitlab env variable into the postStart.exec.command array ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo \"root:{{ENV_VARIABLE}}\" | chpasswd"]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and escape the brackets with
Or there might be some other way in helm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).